# Cancelling China residence permit

Tags: resident-permit, china

I work for the same company, but based in US now. I left China without cancelling the residence permit. I need a business visa to travel there, but now I am told that I need to cancel the permit first. Can it be done locally in Chinese Consulate or through an agency in US? What would be the process for cancelling the permit?

Comment: Can you let me know what happened in your case please. I am in a similar situation, where my work permit in China was cancelled before I exited China in February, but my residence permit was not cancelled and eventually it expired in a month. I was not able to cancel my residence permit as the agent told me, as my spouse's residence(dependent) permit was linked with mine and so mine cannot be cancelled as my spouse left early. I have a business visit now, so I am concerned about applying business visa.

Answer (score 1):

I have not faced this exactly, but I would expect the most normal way is that the company office in China should to go back to the local PSB where they got the permit.
There is a process for revoking it.

They may be reluctant because it may be more expensive and complex with you (or at least your passport) not there.
But I believe it's always that local issuing authority that is expected to do it.
You might push the company to be sure to file the permit cancellation request as showing you did nothing wrong - you mutually agreed to end early.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the individual to complete the proper exit procedure, the company only has to provide the proper exit letter required for that procedure, however most HR departments are setup to help out in this area as it can be quite complex depending on type of VISA and type or work.

Answer (score 1):

Not conducting a proper exit procedure when leaving China can be rather trouble some, but there are agents who can try and help you sort the situation out and file the right papers etc to cancel your residency and ensure you have the proper leave letter etc from your former company which is absolutely critical.

However you must note that even if you complete the exit procedure you might still be denied a new business/tourist visa because of not previously following the rules.

Normally a good visa agent can organize this but as always in China the visa approval process is somewhat person dependent and not always as straightforward as one would wish for.